# Parallax Site with darken image not text

Tags: html, css, overlay, parallax

I am trying to create a parallax webpage with multiple images but I want to make the images darken and the text regular. My images and text are all in the same div since its parralax but maybe theres another way?

```css
.pimg1,
.pimg2,
{
  position: relative;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  filter: brightness(50%);
  height: 100vh;
}

.pimg1 {
  background-image: url('https://www.sticky.digital/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/img-6.jpg');
  min-height: 100%;
}

.pimg2 {
  background-image: url('https://babeltechreviews.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/rendition1.img_.jpg');
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div>
    <img src="https://www.sticky.digital/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/img-6.jpg" class="pimg1">
    <div class="ptext">
      <h1 class="Intro"><strong>Farbod Jahan</strong></h1> <br>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="pimg2">
      <div class="ptext">
        <h1 class="openSans"><strong>Who am I</strong></h1> <br>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: seems like you missing some opening/closing tags

Comment: @Viira Sorry I didn't copy my full code this is just the chunk that should make the difference

Comment: Why are you using both <img> tag and a background image?

Comment: I was trying different methods to bring background image darker while keeping the text bright. Originally its a <div class="pimg1"> like below

Comment: Ok wait let me decode it

Comment: Trying to achieve something like this https://www.taylormccaslin.com/ where the opacity is lower on the image and the text is regular brightness

Comment: I've updated my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use pseudo elements `::before` or `::after`

Here you go. Try this

```css
body{width:100%;}

.pimg1{
    position:relative;
    width:100%; 
    max-width:48%;
    margin-right:1%;
    float:left;
    height:100vh;
    margin-bottom:100px;
}
.pimg1::before{
  content:"";
  background:url('https://www.w3schools.com/html/clouds.jpg') no-repeat fixed center;
  background-size:cover;
  position:absolute; 
  top:0; 
  left:0; 
  height:100%;    
  width:100%;
  filter:brightness(50%);
  z-index:-1;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="pimg1">
        <div class="ptext">
            <h1 class="Intro"><strong>Farbod Jahan</strong></h1> <br>
        </div>
    </div>
  
   <div class="pimg1">
        <div class="ptext">
            <h1 class="Intro"><strong>Farbod Jahan</strong></h1> <br>
        </div>
    </div>

    <p style="padding-top:30px;">Original Image</p>
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/clouds.jpg">
 </body>
```

Comment: This doesn't work it pushes all the content to the top and the images are dark. I have multiple images on the pages that are revealed when scrolling and text overlayed on each  here is the 1st and second pages https://imgur.com/a/riupw8W

Comment: You can align the content if you want to justify them

Comment: It takes away the image and pushes second to the top. Do you want me to just share my whole code?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ey7b5rc9/1/    the page views right on my local but not on jsfiddle, has to do with the images probably

Answer (score 1):

You may looking something like that below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
  <style>
   html, body {
  height:100%;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
 }
    .pimg1, .pimg2 {
  position:relative;
  background-position:center;
  background-size:cover;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
 }
 .pimg1::after, .pimg2::after {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  z-index:0;
  display:block;
 }
 .pimg1 {
  background-image:url('https://via.placeholder.com/550');
  min-height: 100%;
 }
 .pimg2{
  background-image:url('https://via.placeholder.com/550');
  min-height: 100%;
 }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="pimg1">
        <div class="ptext">
            <h1 class="Intro"><strong>Farbod Jahan</strong></h1> <br>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="pimg2">
        <div class="ptext">
            <h1 class="openSans"><strong>Who am I</strong></h1> <br>
        </div>
    </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This just made everything dark rather than just the image